# Array result of a query on mongodb becomes empty after page refresh

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have an array that contains the result of a query on mongodb. At first it is populated but when i refresh the page the array becomes empty. I do not perform a delete at any moment am pretty sure that i dont perform a delete cause i dont have an api for that. I think the problem is related to the fact that the result of the query is a promise. When i restart it all its the same story it is populated at first but when i refresh it is empty again. please help

Here is my angular code:

```
$scope.users = [];
$scope.userss = [];
var Meetup = $resource('/api/user', {},{
  query: {method: 'get', isArray: true}
});
 Meetup.query({text: $rootScope.test},function (results) {
    $scope.users = results;
    console.log('userController scope users '+$scope.users);
  });
```

And my server side code

```
module.exports.listUser = function (req, res) {
  Meetup.find({text: req.query.text}, function (err, results) {
    res.json(results);
  });
}
```

and my html partial

```
<div ng-controller="userController">
     <h1>There are {{users.length}} users</h1>
     <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="user in users">
       {{user.name}}
     </li>
     </ul>
     <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="users in userss">
       {{users.username}}+{{users.auto}}
     </li>
     </ul>

  </div>
```

Comment: Hey Mikiyas, its difficult to tell whats going on with this little information but can you share the server side code or more of the angular code?  from what i understand, i think`{text: $rootScope.test}` gets reset when you reload your angular app.

Comment: okay how do i make it stay still i will edit the question

Comment: maybe you could save the content of `$rootScope.test` on a localstorage so that u'll have access to the content after a page reload. Check this module out it will simplify it for you [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Comment: no luck any other idea

Comment: can you quickly put your html code too?